# Search a file using two strings on the same line from another file with grep or another tool

Tags: grep, awk

I'm tring to grep strings by files. The issue is, grep doesn't do well with lines that have multiple strings (that I know of), which I want to grep individually. Grep may not be the easiest solution here, but it's what I know, so it's what I'm using. In short, I have 2 files I'm using. The first file (file2.txt) that I'm searching is setup as follows:

```
a c  
d  
f  
g  
b h  
h
```

The second file (file1.txt) that I'm using as my search argument is as follows:

```
a b
```

I get no return When I search with grep using:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

However I would like a return that brings me these lines because "a" and "b" are found in them in file2:

```
a c
b h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do is convert `file1.txt` to a newline-separated stream, and pass that to `grep -f` via stdin:

```
$ tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file1.txt | grep -Ff- file2.txt
a c
b h
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick.